# Why does my JMeter results tree show requests, but they are not shown in the test plan's Recording Controller?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to record a test using http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf I've followed all the steps with the following differences:

1. as a server name I used blabla.dev (which is mapped to localhost in /etc/hosts/)
2. I used port 8085 instead of 8080 for the proxy.
3. I'm using Chrome instead of Iceweasel
4. I've used ** and /api/** in patterns to include (assuming ant style pattern matching works)
5. I'm pretty sure there is no other difference, but let's not assume that I'm always right.

My page loads fine in the browser; I can see the requests in View Results Tree. But nothing shows up in the Recording Controller. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jmeter uses Perl-like regex, `**` means "any number of stars". Try `.*` to match everything.